# Visual Studio 2012 Very Slow Typing

Tags: visual-studio, debug, visual-studio-2012, exceptions

I have a problem. After SP1 update, passing some time, VS 2012 becomes very-very slow when typing text. Solution size is not big, PC is quite powerful, it has 16GB of RAM, SSD drive, and i7-2600. I have attached using another VS and I see in debugger a lot of exceptions:

```
First-chance exception at 0x753BB9BC in devenv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CVcsException at memory location 0x0027DF0C.
First-chance exception at 0x753BB9BC in devenv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CVcsException at memory location 0x0027DF0C.
First-chance exception at 0x753BB9BC (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131509, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x64BF0000).
First-chance exception at 0x753BB9BC in devenv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CVcsException at memory location 0x0027DF0C.
First-chance exception at 0x753BB9BC in devenv.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CVcsException at memory location 0x0027DF0C.
First-chance exception at 0x753BB9BC (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0xE0434352 (parameters: 0x80131509, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x64BF0000).
The thread 0x288c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Anyone have any ideas on what CVcsException is? Googling it gives almost nothing. How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Aside form attaching the debugger, what have you tried already to recify this? Have you tried disabling all VS extensions/plug-ins?  Have you tried reinstalling VS?

Comment: Thank you for your help, guys, it seems I understand why this exception is difficult to google. Now I'm sure on 90% that it is connected with new in SP1 feature "Code map". I have reinstalled studio, lagging gone. Then created one Code Map and terrible lagging came back. I will write to Microsoft support and post updates here soon.